# How to make sure div in background isn't visible until hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For my mobile website I have two full screen divs, e.g.:

```
<div id="splash-page"> ... </div>
<div id="content"> ... </div>
```

I have set up the z-indexs so that `#splash-page` is on top of `#content`. This is because I would like it so that `#content` is not visible until I call `$("#splash-page").hide()`.

Here's my CSS:

```
#landing {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

However, when this page loads on a slow connection, sometimes `#content` is visible and then `#splash-page` covers it.

What is the best way to achieve the desired effect without doing an AJAX load or something else complicated with `#content`?

Comment: How about setting `display: none;` for `#content` in css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about just hiding #content initially, instead of doing it through z-index?
Then you can call `$("#spalsh-page").hide(); and $("#content").show();` in tandem.

I would put a `display:none;` style on #content initially

Comment: TGH do you mean `$("#spalsh-page").hide()`

Answer (score 3):

use css and set display to none by default:

```
#content
{
display:none;
}
```